# Elassandra not starting on Windows 10

Tags: elassandra

I am exploring Elassandra as a data store and trying to get it working on my Windows 10 machine.

Downloaded : 
https://github.com/strapdata/elassandra/releases/download/v6.2.3.3/elassandra-6.2.3.3.zip

Confirgured Environmment Variables as Required :

CASSANDRA_HOME: C:\Spike Items\Database Explore\Elassandra\elassandra-6.2.3.3
JAVA_HOME : C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_171

It gives below error, have followed all there recommendations.
Error says JSR223 is not found.

> PS C:\Spike Items\Database Explore\Elassandra\elassandra-6.2.3.3\bin> .\cassandra.ps1 -f -e
>   Get-ChildItem : Cannot find path 'C:\Spike Items\Database Explore\Elassandra\elassandra-6.2.3.3\lib\jsr223' because it
>   does not exist.
>   At C:\Spike Items\Database Explore\Elassandra\elassandra-6.2.3.3\conf\cassandra-env.ps1:212 char:25
>   + ... ach ($jsrDir in Get-ChildItem -Path "$env:CASSANDRA_HOME\lib\jsr223")
>   +                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\Spike Items....3.3\lib\jsr223:String) [Get-ChildItem], ItemNotFound
>      Exception
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand

```
WARNING!  Automatic page file configuration detected.
It is recommended that you disable swap when running Cassandra
for performance and stability reasons.


WARNING! Detected a power profile other than High Performance.
Performance of this node will suffer.
Modify conf\cassandra.env.ps1 to suppress this warning.
```

Starting with Elasticsearch enabled.
Error: Could not find or load main class Items\Database

Answer (score 0):

I have moved on to use Docker on Windows 10 and below Image : 
https://hub.docker.com/r/strapdata/elassandra/

Everything works perfect able to connect to cassandra with DevCenter by mapping internal docker container ports to host ports.

docker run --name el -p 9042:9042 -p 9200:9200 strapdata/elassandra:6.2.3.3